# Allow adding Bug/Task/Issue to Feature in TFS

Tags: tfs, tfs-web-access

I want to allow users to add a Bug /Task or issue to the Feature **through the Board or Backlog** but currently I can only add "User Story" to a Feature. If I open the Feature, then I can add the Bug/Task/Issue as a "Related Work".

Answer (score 0):

As you are using TFS 2013, you can customize your team project so that bugs or other WITs appear in either the backlog or the task board, but not both.

To add bugs or other WITs to backlogs, you can configure team settings or customize your team project to support these choices (need **TFS2013.4 or later**):

- **Option A**: [Allow teams to choose to track bugs on the backlog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/jj920163%28v=vs.120%29.aspx#opt_a)
- **Option B**: [All teams track bugs or additional WITs on the backlog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/jj920163%28v=vs.120%29.aspx#opt_b)